# How to set an automatically generated radio button to true in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating an Excel sheet in which the radio buttons are automatically generated based on the value of specific parameter. Please refer this for clear understanding:

A group of radio buttons are copied `n` number of times. where `n` is the number of rows that refers to a parameter.

Each radio buttons in this auto-generated matrix should be checked against a condition and one of the twelve radio button should be set to True in one group that matches the condition. The main complication here is that, each group of radio buttons are copied to required rows based on the requirement and so, the radio buttons are generated n*12 times and i don't know how to program each radio button that is generated automatically.

I need to know, which Function can I use to fulfill my requirement.

I have created the matrix with the following code:

```
    Dim n, m, i, j, x, k, a As Integer
n = (Sheets("ALLO").Range("E4").Value) * 2       
x = Sheets("ALLO").Range("E3").Value
m = (Sheets("ALLO").Range("E5").Value) + 1
a = m

For i = 2 To n Step 2                               
Sheets("Dummy_Result").Range("A2:M2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("A" & i)
Next i

For j = 3 To n Step 2
Sheets("Dummy_Result").Range("A3:M3").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("A" & j)
Next j

For k = n + 1 To m Step 1
Sheets("Dummy_Result").Range("A3:M3").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("A" & k)
Next k

End Sub
```

My updated Program, for generating the buttons automatically for the range dependent on the value of 'm'. The number of buttons generated should be directly proportional to the value of 'm'. This Program doesn't work when I use the dynamic range instead of Fixed range (As suggested by Mr.JosephC)

```
Sub Test()
    Dim n, m, i, j, x, k, a As Integer
    n = (Sheets("ALLO").Range("E4").Value) * 2       'No of Tack stations
    x = Sheets("ALLO").Range("E3").Value
    m = (Sheets("ALLO").Range("E5").Value) + 1
    a = m

    For i = 2 To n Step 2                               'Correct
    Sheets("Dummy_Result").Range("A2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Results_1").Range("A" & i)
    Call AddOptionButtons(Sheets("Results_1").Range("B & m: M & m"))
    Next i

    For j = 3 To n Step 2
    Sheets("Dummy_Result").Range("A3").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Results_1").Range("A" & j)
Call AddOptionButtons(Sheets("Results_1").Range("B & m: M & m"))

    Next j

    For k = n + 1 To m Step 1
    Sheets("Dummy_Result").Range("A3").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Results_1").Range("A" & k)
Call AddOptionButtons(Sheets("Results_1").Range("B & m: M & m"))
    Next k


End Sub

Private Sub AddOptionButtons(ByRef TargetRange As Range)

    Dim oCell As Range
    For Each oCell In TargetRange
        oCell.RowHeight = 20
        oCell.ColumnWidth = 6
        Dim oOptionButton As OLEObject
        Set oOptionButton = TargetRange.Worksheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.OptionButton.1", Left:=oCell.Left + 1, Top:=oCell.Top + 1, Width:=15, Height:=18)
        oOptionButton.Name = "ob" & oCell.row & "_" & oCell.Column 
        'oOptionButton.Object.Caption = "Button"             oOptionButton.Object.GroupName = "grp" & oCell.Top
    Next
End Sub**strong text**
```

[Please refer the Dummy result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blec6.jpg)

Comment: `Dim n, m, i, j, x, k, a As Integer` only a will be of integer, you need an as per variable.  Not related, just a tip

Comment: Thank you dude. Will see to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add option buttons to each cell in the target range.  It will resize the cells a bit to try and make enough space for them (you can fiddle with placement of the option buttons and size of the cells as you see fit).  It will name the option buttons with their "index" values based on the row and column numbers they are set in ie. ob2_4 is option button in row 2, column 4 (D).  It will also set the group name to be the same for all option buttons on the same row.

```
Sub Test()
    Call AddOptionButtons(Sheet1.Range("B5:D7"))
End Sub

Private Sub AddOptionButtons(ByRef TargetRange As Range)

    Dim oCell As Range
    For Each oCell In TargetRange
        oCell.RowHeight = 20
        oCell.ColumnWidth = 6
        Dim oOptionButton As OLEObject
        Set oOptionButton = TargetRange.Worksheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.OptionButton.1", Left:=oCell.Left + 1, Top:=oCell.Top + 1, Width:=15, Height:=18)
        oOptionButton.Name = "ob" & oCell.Row & "_" & oCell.Column 'Name them to make it easier if you need to access them later
        'oOptionButton.Object.Caption = "Caption" ' If you want to add text to the buttons
        oOptionButton.Object.GroupName = "grp" & oCell.Top
    Next
End Sub
```

*Personal note:
As an aside, please use meaningful names for your variables.  :)  The only time you should use single character variables is if you have hardware requirements on the footprint of your code.*

Comment: Thank you very much for interest in my question. I will try with this suggestion and update an edit.

Comment: I tried the suggestions you have made. The Program you have suggested is working but still, my requirement is using a range that is dependent on another variable. So i have modified your code slightly to make it fit for dynamic range. It is not working now.

Comment: The test part of my code was just to show how it launches (not meant as part of the solution).  The `AddOptionButtons` procedure was designed using a range to allow it to be dynamic.  If I'm understanding your results properly, you shouldn't need to call the procedure in your Title building loops, just once at the end. `Call AddOptionButtons(Sheets("Results_1").Range("B2:M" & m))`  Also you'll want to leave in the groupName part of the procedure, as it will allow one selection per row vs one selection for all option buttons.

Answer (score 2):

This is just something to get you started. Imagine you have 6 Form Controls Option buttons like this:

[image]

Then, if you pass them in an array `buttons1` you may loop through them by their index and assign their value to `True`, based on another array with conditions `condition1`:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim condition1 As Variant
    condition1 = Array(False, True, False, False, False, False)

    Dim buttons1 As Variant
    buttons1 = Array("Option Button 2", "Option Button 3", "Option Button 4", _
                    "Option Button 5", "Option Button 6", "Option Button 7")

    Dim cnt As Long
    For cnt = LBound(buttons1) To UBound(buttons1)
        With Worksheets(1).Shapes(buttons1(cnt)).OLEFormat
            If condition1(cnt) Then .Object.Value = True
        End With
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

Thus, after running the code, as far as the second unit in the `condition1` array is `True`, the `Option Button 3` is selected.

Comment: I thank you for your interest in answering my question. I will try with this concept and share an edit soon.

Comment: Nice idea there +

Comment: Dude, I think this idea is very useful for my second step. I will certainly try to integrate this Idea in the later part.