# How to set an automatically generated Option Button to 'True' based on the value in another range in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I generated radio buttons with the help of the answer to [How to set an automatically generated radio button to true in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53171109/how-to-set-an-automatically-generated-radio-button-to-true-in-vba).

My requirement is to set the automatically generated Option button to 'True' when there is a value **x** in another sheet.

Figure 1: The source to check the value.
[image]

Figure 2: The sheet to which the Mark **x** should be reflected as True.
[image]

The radio buttons that are generated are as Indexed as OB2_2 for the option button in 2 row and 2 column.

Here is the code

```
Private Sub AddOptionButtons(ByRef TargetRange As Range)

Dim m As Variant
m = Sheets("ALLO").Range("D23").Value + 1

Sheets("Final").Range("A2:A" & m).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Int_Result").Range("A2:A" & m)

Dim oCell As Range
For Each oCell In TargetRange
    oCell.RowHeight = 20
    oCell.ColumnWidth = 6
    Dim oOptionButton As OLEObject
    Set oOptionButton = TargetRange.Worksheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.OptionButton.1", Left:=oCell.Left + 1, Top:=oCell.Top + 1, Width:=15, Height:=18)
    oOptionButton.Name = "OB" & oCell.row & "_" & oCell.Column
    oOptionButton.Object.GroupName = "grp" & oCell.Top

Next
Call OB2_Click(oCell)

End Sub

Sub OB2_Click(oCell)

Dim col, ro, m As Variant
Dim Shap As Shape
m = Sheets("ALLO").Range("D23").Value + 1

For Each Shap In Sheets("Int_Result").Shapes
    For ro = 2 To m Step 1
        For col = 1 To 13 Step 1
            If Sheets("Final").Cells(ro, col).Value = "" Then
               Sheets("Int_Result").Shapes(ro, col).ControlFormat.Value = False
            Else
               Sheets("Int_Result").Shapes(ro, col).ControlFormat.Value = True
            End If
        Next col
    Next ro
Next Shap

End Sub
```

I get

> "Object variable or With block variable not set" or "Wrong number of arguments or Invalid Property assignment".

on this line

```
Sheets("Int_Result").Shapes(ro, col).ControlFormat.Value = False
```

How do I access the automatically generated radio buttons?

Comment: What line do you get an error on?

Comment: Hi, there, I get an error in this Line, `Sheets("Int_Result").Shapes(ro, col).ControlFormat.Value = False`

Comment: `Shapes(ro, col)`  Shapes only takes one argument

Comment: Ok I get it Thank you. So, How can I reference a shape (OptionButton) present in a specific cell, so that I can set them to true or  False?

Comment: May try using  `Sheets("Int_Result").OLEObjects("OB" & ro & "_" & Col)` instead of `Sheets("Int_Result").Shapes(ro, col)`

Comment: Hallo @AhmedAU , I have tried your solution. A new error Stating, "Subscript Out of Range "occurs. I have read the Online help, It states the answer related to arrays, of no array being used in my code.       https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/subscript-out-of-range-error-9

Comment: If you try to specify an `OLEObject` that doesn't exist you'd get that error. (eg if you only had 4 objects and you tried to tell excel to adjust the object 5, it would give you this error)

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Thank you for the explanation.I again tried to solve this error by defining another variable as OLEobjects and using Set function. But this gives the same old error as  "Object does not support this property or method"     `Set Obvariant = Sheets("In_Result").OLEObjects("OB" & ro & "_" & col).Activate`

Comment: @AhmedAU It leads to an error straight away for using Quotes dude.

Comment: Thank you again for your interest dude, There comes an Automation Error in turn, stating "items with specified name cannot be found". I will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
 Sheets("Int_Result").OLEObjects("OB2_2").Object.Value = True
```

Set loop not for shapes, but normal to last row and last column.

So for example:

```
Dim oCell As Range
Dim LastCell As Range
For Each oCell In TargetRange
    oCell.RowHeight = 20
    oCell.ColumnWidth = 6
    Dim oOptionButton As OLEObject
    Set oOptionButton = TargetRange.Worksheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.OptionButton.1", Left:=oCell.Left + 1, Top:=oCell.Top + 1, Width:=15, Height:=18)
    oOptionButton.Name = "OB" & oCell.Row & "_" & oCell.Column
    oOptionButton.Object.GroupName = "grp" & oCell.Top
    Set LastCell = oCell

Next
Call OB2_Click(LastCell)
```

---

```
Sub OB2_Click(oCell as Range)

Dim col As Long, ro As Long
dim m as long, k as long

col = oCell.Column
ro = oCell.Row

For m = 2 to ro
    For k = 2 to col
         If Sheets("Final").Cells(m, k).Value = "" Then
             Sheets("Int_Result").OLEObjects("OB" & m & "_" & k).Object.Value = False
         Else
             Sheets("Int_Result").OLEObjects("OB" & m & "_" & k).Object.Value = True
         End If
    Next k
Next m
End sub
```

Comment: Hallo @Gadziu, Thank for your answer. I have tried your codes, An error stating "Object Variable or With block variable not Set". I actually planned to reference each cell in 'Int_Result' sheet and access the shape present in the cell. which makes the solution simple. But I have problems with the Syntax with which I can refer each Shape in the sheet.

Comment: My solution works. You have this error, because you pass as oCell empty object. After you escape from each for loop your oCell is null. You need to remeber it in other object. Solutions above.

Comment: Hi @Gadziu, It worked really great. I thank you very much for the efforts you have put forth to help me. I still have a small question. In the call statement `Call OB2_Click(LastCell)` the arguement is `LastCell`, but when you are opening the subroutine `OB2_Click` you use oCell. Can you please explain me, how that exactly works? #New to programming dude.

Comment: I passes `LastCell` from `AddOptionButtons`, but in `OB2_Click` I have `oCell as Range`, so I need to use `oCell`

Comment: I was thinking that the arguement which we pass in the Call statement and the argument we get in the Subroutine should be same. Learned that, It could also be different. Thank you once again.